# Reasons behind question migration between the sites?

Tags: support, closed-questions, migration

I've seen a lot of questions with a status of **closed** and the questions migrated across the various Stack Overflow sites.

What purpose, and on what basis, do these questions get migrated from one site to another?

Also, what's the classification between these in the context of the questions asked?

Answer (score 3):

StackOverflow = Programming-related questions - things about programming languages, algorithsm, data structures, implementation details, program design, et cetera - if it's involved in *making* software, it probably goes there.

ServerFault = System administration. OS setup/usage/sysoping, network management, et cetera all go here. If it's about installing/configuring production software/systems, it probably goes there.

SuperUser = General computer usage of all types. If it's a question about computing and it doesn't go on SO or SF, it can probably be asked here.

Meta = Questions *about the other sites* - support issues, questions on community topics, etc; anything that deals with how SO, SF, and SU work.

Comment: This is what an intelligent answer I am actually expecting from you. Thanks. One more point who has the right to move questions from one to another

Comment: Migrating (moving) is a form of closing - as stated in the FAQ (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), users with 250+ reputation can vote to close their *own* questions, users with 3000+ reputation can vote to close others' questions.

Comment: Thanks Dav I am new to stack overflow and not aware of this

Comment: @Dav: Yes, thank you for taking the time to help out a new user.  A lot of other people seem to have forgotten that they were new once too.